# How to turn off anti-aliasing for DrawingBrush?

Tags: wpf

I want to draw a triangle as a border background. One way of doing this is by using a DrawingBrush, but at smaller sizes anti-aliasing is distorting the triangle and making it blurry. **How can I disable anti-aliasing?**

```
<Border>
    <Border.Background>
        <DrawingBrush>
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="Red">
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <PathGeometry>
                            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                                <PathFigureCollection>
                                    <PathFigure IsClosed="True" StartPoint="0,3" IsFilled="True">
                                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                                            <LineSegment Point="3,0" />
                                            <LineSegment Point="6,3" />
                                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                                    </PathFigure>
                                </PathFigureCollection>
                            </PathGeometry.Figures>
                        </PathGeometry>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

I've tried setting RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" and SnapsToDevicePixels="true" on all possible elements, but that hasn't worked...

**Edit:**
This is what the drawn triangle looks like at Width=17; Height=12 (zoomed to 800%):

[image: Blurry triangle]

As you can see the edges are anti-aliased. All the usual options for disabling anti-aliasing don't seem to be working...

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of what it looks like (and the width/height values you used)?

Comment: @H.B. check the edit of my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering there haven't been any more replies, then it seems that the answer is - it's impossible.

Answer (score 4):

I also became very frustrated with this. After some research, I found the answer: Using a Visual Brush with the Image element in the visual set to SnapToDevicePixels = true and Aliased Edge Mode. See the example below:

```
            <Canvas VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="12" Margin="0,24,0,0">
                <Canvas.Background>
                    <VisualBrush  TileMode="Tile"  Stretch="None" Viewport="-5,0,10,10" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <Image Stretch="None" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <DrawingImage>
                                        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                                            <GeometryDrawing>
                                                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                                    <Pen Brush="#8F8E8F" Thickness="1" />
                                                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,10"/>
                                                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            </GeometryDrawing>
                                        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                                    </DrawingImage>
                                </Image.Source>
                            </Image>
                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>
                </Canvas.Background>
            </Canvas>
```

Comment: This is long after the fact but I found this to be a perfect solution! .Net4.61, VS2017

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do it with SnapToDevicePixels (although sometimes it takes a little trial and error). You should set it on the owning object (so whatever the border is being put in). Have you read this article?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970908.aspx

Comment: I have tried setting SnapToDevicePixels on all possible elements, starting from the Window all the way down to the Border itself, but it doesn't work. Possibly, because DrawingBrush and it's childern don't have that property... For some reason, it seems that RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" is not honored by DrawingBrush and it's children, so that also doesn't work. I have read the article you linked, but sadly it doesn't help in this specific scenario.